# Unable to click an element within iframe in IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I want to click on an element as follows:

```
//select[@name='instructionSelection']
```

But its not clicking with Selenium on IE 11.

HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to iframe using `name=InvoiceDeatils` before interacting with the element.

Not sure which language you are using. Providing the snippet in python below.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('InvoiceDeatils'))
# now click on the element
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='instructionSelection']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)::

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='invoiceDeatils'][src*='invoiceDeatils']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='instructionSelection']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='invoiceDeatils' and contains(@src, 'invoiceDeatils')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='instructionSelection']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)